# $\int _0^1\:2xe^{x^2-1}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

for the answer I'm getting:

$1+\frac{1}{e}$

but according to [symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%202xe%5E%7Bx%5E2-1%7Ddx), I get:

$1-\frac{1}{e}$

steps I'm currently taking with u substitution; I get:

$\int \:e^u$

then plugging back u;

$e^{x^2-1}$ (from 0 to 1)

then I compute,

$e^{-1}+e^0$ = $1+\frac{1}{e}$

I'm not sure

Comment: You are not sure of what? The derivative of $e^{x^2-1}$ is exactly $2x e^{x^2-1}$, hence the integral is trivial to compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the definite integral it would be $e^{1-1} - e^{0-1}$

Comment: ok ha I just saw that i see